# topology made of all sets on R ("closed", "open", "clopen")

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble verifying if the topology generated by any set on R

$( [a,b], (a,b), [a,b), (a,b] : a,b \in R )$

is in fact a topology or not, and if it is, is the boundary what you would expect it to be? (i.e. simply {a,b}).

Thank you :)

Comment: Hint: try to show that every point is open.

Comment: Isn't $(a,b] \cap [b,c) = [b]$ sufficient? But how does every point being open helps me ?

Comment: yes. do you know about discrete topology?

Comment: Oh so this topology is actually the same as the discrete! is that what you're trying to get me to guess ?

Comment: yes. so now what can you say about the boundary?

Comment: it's empty since Clos(A) = interior(A) = A
-Edit : thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topology you're looking for consists of arbitrary unions of finite intersections of sets in the family you're starting with.

Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$; then $(c-1,c]$ and $[c,c+1)$ belong to the family, so their intersection is open in the topology.

Since $c$ is arbitrary, you can conclude the topology is…

Comment: The discrete topology

Comment: @Dominus Yes; that was already suggested, but I wanted to emphasize what the generated topology is.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes more sense, I was slightly confused about whether you expected an answer